# Most recent questions on home page

Tags: discussion

Question for those with more experience than I here: why in the last few days are many of the questions on the home page many years old? I'd really rather see *recent* questions on the home page; am I doing something wrong...? Or is mod activity on these questions inadvertently pushing these to the first page? If the latter, are there alternatives that don't have this undesirable side effect?

As far as I can tell the edits to these questions are all by the community user.

For example;

[Unknown Host Error, is this a registrar problem or a host problem?](https://serverfault.com/questions/180787/unknown-host-error-is-this-a-registrar-problem-or-a-host-problem)

[NFS mounts not visible for other users in system](https://serverfault.com/questions/527889/nfs-mounts-not-visible-for-other-users-in-system)

Comment: Pop in at the weekend you'll see a lot more.

Comment: Thats why I always select by 'newest', not 'active'

Comment: @yagmoth555 I'm going to ask a stupid question now. How do I select 'newest'? I don't see that option on the homepage.

Comment: @Steve365: If you select the red `Questions` box to the right of the site logo you will get to http://serverfault.com/questions. From there you can select tabs like "newest", "featured" etc. The absolute URL is http://serverfault.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: @Sven Aha! Perfect. Many thanks indeed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been going on practically since the site opened:

Once an hour, the system will bump two randomly selected questions which are at least 30 days old and have no upvoted or accepted answers back to the homepage.

Comment: Are they truly random? For some reason, I thought they were based off of recently-active tags.

Comment: Thanks, that explains that then! :)

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely the automatic process that bumps old, unanswered (meaning not accepted or upvoted) questions back to the home page.

[Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511)